# Store java objects as shared preferences with the help of Gson, instead of using SQLite? (Android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, gson

If I want to handle and save a database in an android app, is it a bad idea to build the database as a structure of simple java objects and then save them in shared preferences using gson to convert them to json strings, instead of creating tables in an actual database in for example SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

It always depends, but it it very likely that you would just reinvent the wheel with a solution like that.
Down the road you (most probably) will find yourself slowly reimplementing features that are there by default in SQLite, indexing, foreign keys, etc.

Again, your requirements might justify it somehow, but to evaluate that you would have to tell more about them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem storing json objects. In fact [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.org/) and document databases are built around that concept.

For certain use cases, json is the much more agile / future proof way of storing data when the schema is not concrete. A relational schema can be too heavyweight for some use cases.